# Click event Jquery launching when document is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

I have a function that validates a form and I want it to be triggered when the #submit-btn is clicked but the problem is that it is triggered every time the document is load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit-btn").on('click', validar());
});
```

Comment: You're firing the click event instead of passing it as parameter. Remove the `()` from `validar()`.

Comment: @LucasVicente thank you for answering, I didn't know it worked like that. It works great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the result of your function `validar()` as the EventHandler - effectively calling it the moment the document is loaded.

Just remove the brackets and you'll have the function mapped as EventHandler

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#submit-btn', function(){ 
      validar(); 
      return false; 
    })
```

There is no need for the `$(document).ready()`.
But if the button is a submit button it never will triggered. Change the button type to "button" and after the validate return "true", submit your form manual

```
$('#formId').submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //console.log("Document ready event occurred")

    $(document).on('click','#submit-btn', function(e){

       //console.log("Submit button clicked")

       e.preventDefault();
       validar()

    });
});
```